# Setting up a server for Django app reachable from the outside

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I've written a Django (1.4) app that uses webhooks: at a certain time a POST request is made to my application. For testing purposes I have to try it on my local machine, but I need the application to be reachable (only for now, during development) from the outside.

Now, the problem is that Django dev server runs on the local host (127.0.0.1), which is accessible only from my machine. So I thought to a Gunicorn + nginx server: how can I set it up to fit those requirements?

Thank you,
rubik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout  localtunnel 
http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

It will give you a unique url that is accessible from outside.

Comment: Wow, awesome! At start it didn't find an available port but the it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Dev server can be be seen from outside too with:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Otherwise, setting nginx and gunicorn is easy and well documented.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me. I tried to perform a request using the online tool hurl.it and it failed saying it cannot connect to the server.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. What's sure is that I have not configured any firewall at all. I'm on a machine running ArchLinux so I don't think there is a firewall involved.

Comment: Check, if your server is accessible from outside network, otherwise no it does not matter which server you choose. You can also change port to 80, given there is no started services on that port (ie. shutdown apache or nginx)

Comment: Have you tried accessing it from another machine on your local network?  If that works but you can't access it from outside of the network, you likely have an issue with port forwarding on your router.

Comment: @jonmorgan: I tried with another machine connected to the same router and it does not see it. At this point, I don't know what could cause the problem...

Comment: I would advice to post a new question with details a nd tag it with linux, network, arch-linux. It looks like you have an issue with network access. Also, try to add more information to question: ping machine from other machines from inside and outside network, check if you have any webserver installed/enabled and if it is accessible from inside/outside.

Comment: @bmihelac: Thank you, I will follow your advice as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> To be honest, I don't know. What's sure is that I have not configured
>   any firewall at all. I'm on a machine running ArchLinux so I don't
>   think there is a firewall involved.

To quickly get it up and running from outside your firewall, consider using a PaaS provider like [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. I need to do some files operation (involving virtualenvs), and Heorku's filesystem is read-only. I will go for a dedicated server I think.